# R - Using glmnet with purrr/tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, glmnet, purrr

I am following code from this R Bloggers [link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups/) in order to run models on groups within my data using `tidyr` and `purrr`. However, I would like to use `glmnet` rather than just `lm` on my nested data. Unlike `lm`, `glmnet`/`cv.glmnet` takes a `model.matrix` as the `x` argument and I need to abstract the formula fed to that `model.matrix` and that is what is holding me up.

So this works:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)

mod_test <- mtcars %>%
  nest(-vs) %>%
  mutate(cv_mod = map(data, ~ cv.glmnet(
    x = model.matrix(data = ., .$mpg ~ .$cyl * .$hp)[,-1],
    y = .$mpg
  )))
mod_test
> mod_test
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     vs               data          cv_mod
  <dbl>             <list>          <list>
1     0 <tibble [18 x 10]> <S3: cv.glmnet>
2     1 <tibble [14 x 10]> <S3: cv.glmnet>
```

But when I try to create the formula for the `model.matrix` separately, it does not.

```
mod_form <- as.formula(".$mpg ~ .$cyl * .$hp")

mod_test2 <- mtcars %>%
  nest(-vs) %>%
  mutate(cv_mod = map(data, ~ cv.glmnet(
    x = model.matrix(data = ., mod_form)[,-1],
    y = .$mpg
  )))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object '.' not found
```

Comment: What about `mod_form <- mpg ~ cyl * hp`?

Comment: @mt1022, yep, that seems to do it. I went a little overboard on the `.$`. I suppose that is only needed on the `y` argument because `model.matrix` already gets a `data = .` argument. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part, why `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object '.' not found`? The folowing is my reasoning:

see manual of `as.formula`:

> Formulas created with as.formula will use the env argument for their
>   environment.

When you create `mod_test`: according to `as.formula(object, env = parent.frame())`, it will be `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`.

Next,

> A formula object has an associated environment, and this environment
>   (rather than the parent environment) is used by model.frame to
>   evaluate variables that are not found in the supplied data argument.

So, `model.matrix` will look for columns like `.$mpg` in `data`. Apprently, those columns are called like `mpg` not `.$mpg`. Then it will looks for `.$mpg` in env associated with the formula: R_GlobalEnv. There is no object called `.` in global env. Therefore error was reported.

(correct me if some of this part is wrong.)

---

Second, solution, try:

```
mod_form <- mpg ~ cyl * hp
# or
mod_form <- as.formula('mpg ~ cyl * hp')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [glmnetUtils](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnetUtils) if you want a formula/data frame interface to glmnet. This makes interfacing with the tidyverse a bit more convenient.

```
install.packages("glmnetUtils")

mod_test <- mtcars %>%
  nest(-vs) %>%
  mutate(cv_mod=map(data, ~ cv.glmnet(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data=.)))
```